# Rails NoMethodError for editing the data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to edit my form data of the model but whenever i want to route to movies/1/edit rails gives me an error of NoMethodError in Movies#edit

it shows me this

[This is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR1cG.png)

my controller code

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController
def index
    @movies=Movie.all
end
def new
    @movie=Movie.new
end
def create
    @movie=Movie.new(m_p)
    if @movie.save
        redirect_to movies_path
        flash[:notice]="created"
    end

end

def edit
    @movie=Movie.find(params[:id])

end

def update
    @movie=Movie.find(params[:id])
    if @movie.update(m_p)
        redirect_to movies_path
        flash[:notice]="updated"
    end
end

def show
    @movie=Movie.find(params[:id])
end
private
def m_p
    params.require(:movie).permit(:name,:genre,:hero)
end
```

end

my routes

```
  get 'movies', to: 'movies#index'
  get 'movies/new' ,to: 'movies#new'

  post 'movies', to:'movies#create' #create 

  get 'movies/:id' ,to:'movies#show',:as=>"show"

  get 'movies/:id/edit' ,to:'movies#edit'
   
  patch 'movies/:id' ,to:'movies#update'
```

my edit.html.erb

```
 <h1>edit</h1>
<%#= link_to "howe page", movies_path %>


<%= form_for @movie  do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :genre %>
    <%= f.text_field :hero %>
    <%= f.submit %>
    
<% end %>
```

please help me out :<

Comment: the url helpers are missing, try removing current routes and add `resources :movies` in your route file.

Comment: please post the error message instead of an image

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to set this up is with [resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). It will create all the CRUD routes for you.

```
# routes.rb
resources :movies
```

In addition, `rake routes` returns a list with all the routes you have and when such errors appear you could check it to see what's missing.